# Basic Excel: How to show an interval in a cell rather than a single number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to make a column that lists a +or- 5%variance of a certain calculation.
For example, in column A and B there are a list of numbers and I want column C to show ColumA/ColumnB + or - 5%.

So if `A1 = 10` and `B1 = 12` then I want `C1` to show "`.792 to .875`" or something like "`.792 - .875`" or "`(.792,.875)`".

In order to make it easy to look at, maybe I want a certain format that would change the colors of the 95% # and the 105% number ...
What would one do in these kind of situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CONCATENATE, something like this:

```
=CONCATENATE(ROUND(A1/B1-(A1/B1*0.05),3)," - ",ROUND(A1/B1+(A1/B1*0.05),3))
```

As far as I know there is no way to have multiple formats in one cell containing a formula. It might be posible with VBA.

Comment: It was a pretty easy to follow function and intuitive to use.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SincereApathy's answer doesn't work for me. Based on his answer, but using in-line concatenation instead of the `CONCATENATE` function:

```
=ROUND((A1/B1-0,05);3) & " - " & ROUND((A1/B1+0,05);3)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get what your looking for you could use the text function.

You will have to generate the text with a formula, something like 
="(" & text(c1,".000") & " - " & text(d1,".000") & ")"
Where c1 and d1 are the ranges you wish to show.

To get it to format with colour you can use conditional formatting on c1 and d1 to colour the cell where your formula is.